# tab content not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my code i want every tab-content should be hidden then when i click on the menu then the menu wise contents will open,I've done all these so far.now i want when i click the menu it should slideDown the content slowly and again if i click on that menu the content should be closed with slideUp .

```
    $(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   // $('.tab-content').slideDown('slow');
    $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').removeClass('active');  
    $('.tab-content').hide().slideDown(600);       
    });
```

I want when like this but not happening actually. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/otpq2c5j/29/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs .col-3 a').click(function(e) { // Or bind to any other event you like, or call manually
    e.preventDefault();
    var hrefid = $(this).attr("href");
    var tabid = ($(this).attr("href")).replace('#', ''); // remove #         
    var getContent = $(hrefid).html();

    $('#maintabcontent').hide().html(getContent).stop().fadeIn(1400);

    $('span.plus').text("+");
    var $t = $('.tab-container');
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).find('span').text("+");
      $t.slideUp(function() {
        $('#maintabcontent').html('');
      });
      $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).find('span').text("-");
      $t.slideDown(600, function() {

      });
      if ($t.is(':visible')) {
        $('.col-3').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.full-width {
    background: #dfdedb none repeat scroll 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1220px;
}
.padding-top-bottom-small {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.col-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 403px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 32.5%;
}
.tabs .col-3 {
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-container {
    background: #505050 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
.main-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1220px;
}
.padding-top-bottom-big {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-width container tabs">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="col-3 first text-center padding-top-bottom-small"> <a href="#tab-1"><h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">How to Sell <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span></h3></a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-3 second text-center padding-top-bottom-small"> <a href="#tab-2"><h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Finance <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span></h3></a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center padding-top-bottom-small"> <a href="#tab-3"><h3 class="lato-reg mediumfontx4 orange">Market Intelligence <span class="deep-grey padding-left-tiny plus" data-tab="tab-1">+</span></h3></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
    <div class="main-container padding-top-bottom-big" id="maintabcontent"></div>
</div>
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">Tab Content 1</div>
<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Tab Content 2</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Tab Content 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```js
$('.tab-content').hide();  

$(document).on('click','.nav-link:not(.active)', function(){
  $('.tab-content').slideDown("slow");       
});

$(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
  $('.tab-content').slideToggle("slow");       
});
```

```css
.tab-pane{
  background-color:red;
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
.tab-content{
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">Good</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">Best</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">Poor</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">Ugly</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much...The perfect answer I've been looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/otpq2c5j/38/

```js
$(document).on('click','.nav-link', function(){
  $('.tab-pane').slideUp('fast');
  $($(this).attr('href')).slideDown('slow');
});
```

```css
.tab-pane{
  background-color:red;
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
.tab-content{
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">Good</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">Best</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">Poor</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">Ugly</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple CSS. Instead of the code `$('.tab-content').hide().slideDown(600);`
use `transition: height 1s;` in your `active` class in css.

What this does is, smoothly transitions from the previous class to the `active` class. There are many customizations that you can do to the transition effect. Take a look at the transition attributes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add active class to first tab-content div

<div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">Good</div>

Update css like this

.tab-content{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
.tab-pane.active{
  display:block;
}

Update js file like this

 $(document).on('click','.nav-link', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        //$(this).removeClass('active');
       // $('.tab-content').slideDown('slow');
        $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').slideToggle(600);       
        });
```

Comment: i don't wanna show content first ,I want when i  click on the menu the content should open.If i put active class then it would be shown the content from the first